# Using std::any_of, std::all_of, std::none_of etc with std::map

Tags: c++, std

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, bool> str_bool_map = {
    {"a", true},
    {"b", false},
    {"c", true}
};
```

can we use `std::any_of` on this map to see any of its values is `false`? Or any of its key is let's say `"d"`?

Similarly can we use `std::all_of` or `std::none_of` on this map?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use a lambda:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, bool> str_bool_map = 
    {{"a", true}, {"b", false}, {"c", true}};

bool f = std::any_of(str_bool_map.begin(), str_bool_map.end(),
    [](const auto& p) { return !p.second; });
```

Here the lambda expression `[](...) { ... }` is a unary predicate that takes `const auto& p` and makes the test. `const auto&` will be deduced to `const std::pair<const std::string, bool>&` (= `std::unordered_map<...>::value_type`), that's why you use `.second` to test the `bool` part of a pair. Use `.first` member to test the element's key.

Comment: thanks, I was not writing the predicate correctly and thought it does not work

Answer (score 5):

Quick answer: What happens when you try?

Another quick answer: Yes

Reason: Looking at [this page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of) we can see that `std::all_of` and friends expect that:

> InputIt must meet the requirements of *LegacyInputIterator*.

Now, [`std::map.begin()` returns](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) a *LegacyBidirectionalIterator*

Finally, looking at [the table here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) we can see that *LegacyBidirectionalIterator* is a kind of *LegacyInputIterator*, so therefore you can use an `std::map` with `std::all_of` and friends.

Comment: thanks, I was not writing the predicate correctly and thought it does not work

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, bool> map;
    map["foo"] = false;
    map["bar"] = true;
    map["baz"] = false;

    const bool any = std::any_of(map.begin(), map.end(), [](const auto& pair)
    {
        return !pair.second;
    });

    const bool all = std::all_of(map.begin(), map.end(), [](const auto& pair)
    {
        return !pair.second;
    });

    const bool none_of = std::none_of(map.begin(), map.end(), [](const auto& pair)
    {
        return !pair.second;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over a map yields key-value pairs. So you can just pass a lambda to the algorithm to unpack the key value pair.

To check a val, use `.second`:

```
std::any_of(m.begin(), m.end(), [](const auto& kvp){ return kvp.second; });
```

To check keys, use `.first`:

```
std::any_of(m.begin(), m.end(), [](const auto& kvp){ return kvp.first == "d"; })
```

Live code [here](https://ideone.com/oAn7Wo).